# What is the best way to scale a numerical dataset

Tags: data-mining, dataset, beginner, feature-scaling

I have a dataset with differents attributes which don't have the same range on their values which is a problem when we need to compute distance beetween objects. After some research i found that i can do the regularisation job with this formula : (value-min)/(max-min)  where min and max are respectively the minimum and maximum value in the domain of val attribute.
The question is that one, does it exist other ways ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by scale, but that sounds like the answer to your question. What else are you looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is pretty much mess in terminology in your question :).
**[Data Regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics))** is used for model selection, it is not about data processing. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4961/what-is-regularization-in-plain-english) it is described in more friendly manner.

What you mean is **[Feature Scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling)**. It can be done in **several** ways including **[Rescaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling#Rescaling)**, the method you described. You may also use Standardization (normalization) and Scaling to unit length.

These answers may be helpful:

- [Normalization vs Scaling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35591/normalization-vs-scaling)
- [Normalization vs Standardization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10289/whats-the-difference-between-normalization-and-standardization)